# jQuery: on() attached click elements bleed through overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, overlay

What I have is grid of divs to whom I attach click handlers by using jQuery .on() function. When one of elements is clicked on, partly transparent DIV is faded in as overlay over this grid to prevent another element being clicked while dialog box is open.

The problem is that for some strange reason .on('click') events still bleed through overlay layer, as if it wasn't there - I suspect that .on() function is to blame, because when I simply use .click() handler, this overlay works fine.

I've tried suggestions to use event.stopPropagation on overlay div to keep this from happening, but I've so far had no luck.

Simplified example:

HTML:

```
<div class="grid-cointainer">
    <div class="grid-item">1</div>
    <div class="grid-item">2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">3</div>
    <div class="grid-item">4</div>
</div>
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.grid-container { 
   position: absolute; 
   top: 0px; 
   left: 0px; 
   width: 400px; 
   height: 100px;
}
.grid-item { 
   float: left; 
   display: inline-block; 
   width: 100px; 
   height: 100px; 
   background-color: #666;
}
.overlay {  
   position: absolute; 
   top: 0px; 
   left: 0px; 
   width: 400px; 
   height: 100px; 
   background-color: #fff; 
   display: none; 
   opacity: 0.5; 
   z-index: 999 
}
```

JS:

```
 $('.grid-item').on( "click", function() { 
      showAwesomeDialog(this); 
      $('.overlay').css("display","block"); 
 });
```

Comment: Using `click` to bind events is just a shortcut for `on('click', ...)`, so there has to be something else that differs in the code.

Comment: It seems to work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/W5LjM/.  The only issue I see is that the overlay doesn't entirely cover the container because you have a misspelling in the class name as "grid-cointainer" should be "grid-container" to match the CSS.